# Quantum corrections in Holography

Tags: conformal-field-theory, string, ads-cft, holographic-principle

AdS/CFT stablish that there is some kind of correspondence between the ${\cal N}=4$ SYM theory and strings in $AdS_5\times S^5$ space-time. I know, for instance that 1/2 BPS operators like Tr$(\phi_1^J)$ in the ${\cal N}=4$ side corresponds to some null geodesic in the $AdS_5\times S^5$:
$$ u_1+iu_2 = e^{i\tau J},\ \ \  v_1+iv_2 = e^{i\tau E} $$
where $u_i$ are embedding coordinates for the sphere and $v_i$ embedding coordinates for the AdS space. We can compute the conformal dimension of this 1/2 BPS state and find $\Delta = J$. We can compute the energy of this null geodesic using the virasoro constraint $T_{\mu\nu}=0$, and find $E=J$. Ok! the correspondence works.

We can compute loop corrections for $\Delta$ and see that it does not suffears such quantum corrections. How can we approach this quantum corrections in the string side?